# FreeRADIUS Google Dual Factor Authenticator, Pam

Tags: pam, freeradius, google-authenticator

Hi I've been following this article to setup FreeRADIUS Google Dual Factor Authenticator

http://www.supertechguy.com/help/security/freeradius-google-auth

Hours of testing I still can't get it to work. If my /etc/pam.d/radiusd looks like the following it works well with 
the following command

radtest test test localhost 18120 testing123

```
#
# /etc/pam.d/radiusd - PAM configuration for FreeRADIUS
#

# We fall back to the system default in /etc/pam.d/common-*
#

@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-password
@include common-session
```

However if it looks like the following

```
#
# /etc/pam.d/radiusd - PAM configuration for FreeRADIUS
#

# We fall back to the system default in /etc/pam.d/common-*
#

#@include common-auth
#@include common-account
#@include common-password
#@include common-session

auth requisite pam_google_authenticator.so forward_pass
auth required pam_unix.so use_first_pass
```

my log file says the following and auth fails.

```
rad_recv: Access-Request packet from host 127.0.0.1 port 43185, id=111, length=56
        User-Name = "test"
        User-Password = "test"
        NAS-IP-Address = 127.0.1.1
        NAS-Port = 18120
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Info: # Executing section authorize from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Info: +- entering group authorize {...}
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Info: ++[preprocess] returns ok
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Info: ++[chap] returns noop
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Info: ++[mschap] returns noop
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Info: ++[digest] returns noop
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Info: [suffix] No '@' in User-Name = "test", looking up realm NULL
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Info: [suffix] No such realm "NULL"
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Info: ++[suffix] returns noop
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Info: [eap] No EAP-Message, not doing EAP
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Info: ++[eap] returns noop
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Info: [files] users: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 74
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Info: ++[files] returns ok
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Info: ++[expiration] returns noop
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Info: ++[logintime] returns noop
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Info: [pap] WARNING! No "known good" password found for the user.  Authentication may fail because of this.
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Info: ++[pap] returns noop
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Info: Found Auth-Type = PAM
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Info: # Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Info: +- entering group authenticate {...}
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Debug: pam_pass: using pamauth string <radiusd> for pam.conf lookup
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Debug: pam_pass: function pam_authenticate FAILED for <test>. Reason: Cannot make/remove an entry for the specified session
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Info: ++[pam] returns reject
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Info: Failed to authenticate the user.
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Info: Using Post-Auth-Type Reject
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Info: # Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Info: +- entering group REJECT {...}
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Info: [attr_filter.access_reject]    expand: %{User-Name} -> test
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Debug:  attr_filter: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 11
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Info: ++[attr_filter.access_reject] returns updated
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Info: Delaying reject of request 0 for 1 seconds
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Debug: Going to the next request
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Debug: Waking up in 0.9 seconds.
Thu Sep 26 16:38:20 2013 : Info: Sending delayed reject for request 0
Sending Access-Reject of id 111 to 127.0.0.1 port 43185
Thu Sep 26 16:38:20 2013 : Debug: Waking up in 4.9 seconds.
Thu Sep 26 16:38:25 2013 : Info: Cleaning up request 0 ID 111 with timestamp +3
Thu Sep 26 16:38:25 2013 : Info: Ready to process requests.
```

I'm using Ubuntu latest

Does anyone know what the issue here?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After so much internet surfing and forum hunting I manage to fix this problem. If anyone else having this issue this might help them :)

```
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Debug: pam_pass: using pamauth string <radiusd> for pam.conf lookup
Thu Sep 26 16:38:19 2013 : Debug: pam_pass: function pam_authenticate FAILED for <test>. Reason: Cannot make/remove an entry for the specified session
```

The above line actually means a auth fail, even though it doesn't sound like it, also it could mean that .google_authenticator file in the user's home directory isn't accessible.

FreeRadius log file not help you much with this issue, but have a look through /var/log/secure on CentOS and /var/log/auth.log in Ubuntu. This will explain which is the issue.

Issue with my system was my time was out and my random generated number by Google Dual Factor Authenticator application on my iPhone wasn't valid. I had to install NTP and change my servers time to the correct time which fixed the issue!!!!

hope this help someone else :)

Answer (score -1):

The how-to on Super Tech Guy's page (http://www.supertechguy.com/help/security/freeradius-google-auth) has a typo.

```
DEFAULT        Auth-Type := PAM
```

should be

```
DEFAULT        Auth-Type = PAM
```

I don't know why he put a colon in there, but removing it fixed my issue.

This was after I made sure the server had the correct time (and timezone), which it didn't. So thanks for that suggestion too!